# Масив php, вывести данные

Tags: php, массивы

Здраствуйте, пожалуйста помогайте чайнику :)

```
  array(5) {
  ["current_count"]=>
  int(50)
  ["hasNextPage"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["limit"]=>
  int(50)
  ["offset"]=>
  int(0)
  ["result"]=>
  array(50) {
    [0]=>
    array(16) {
      ["artist_id"]=>
      int(112128437)
      ["artist_name"]=>
      string(11) "THRILL PILL"
      ["bitrate"]=>
      int(125)
      ["duration"]=>
      string(4) "3:46"
      ["duration_seconds"]=>
      int(226)
      ["file"]=>
      string(214) "https://cdn1.mp3go.dev/api/file/8473f0488189f6a64b64992c53da048d.mp3?hash=gAAAAABeFKn-d7hUONcEI4BB75TqwrA7joE1cRujZ2xdqBI7D5L-SpAQ3lKnMJNLn4XKna2XWqChoS1p0Bqw9ltyp-er9hL_0XD615wEno4t8j9G-TUzSRmEvzdZzXhNnJDR8mySVl2S"
      ["file_size"]=>
      string(3) "3.5"
      ["genre_objs"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(110)
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "Рэп"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(111)
          ["name"]=>
          string(21) "Русский рэп"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(113)
          ["name"]=>
          string(13) "Хип-хоп"
        }
      }
      ["genres"]=>
      string(21) "Русский рэп"
      ["id"]=>
      int(19173534)
      ["image"]=>
      string(47) "https://mp3go.dev/api/tracks/19173534/cover.jpg"
      ["position"]=>
      int(2)
      ["release_id"]=>
      int(2755739)
      ["release_title"]=>
      string(20) "ОТКРОВЕНИЯ"
      ["title"]=>
      string(68) "Грустная Песня (feat. Егор Крид & MORGENSHTERN)"
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(16) {
      ["artist_id"]=>
      int(105371365)
      ["artist_name"]=>
      string(6) "Zivert"
      ["bitrate"]=>
      int(125)
      ["duration"]=>
      string(4) "3:01"
      ["duration_seconds"]=>
      int(181)
      ["file"]=>
      string(214) "https://cdn1.mp3go.dev/api/file/10a1ebca0767d346b38ea89b8f61a1e4.mp3?hash=gAAAAABeFKn-d7hUONcEI4BB75TqwrA7joE1cRujZ2xdqBI7D5L-SpAQ3lKnMJNLn4XKna2XWqChoS1p0Bqw9ltyp-er9hL_0XD615wEno4t8j9G-TUzSRmEvzdZzXhNnJDR8mySVl2S"
      ["file_size"]=>
      string(3) "2.8"
      ["genre_objs"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(115)
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "Поп"
        }
      }
      ["genres"]=>
      string(6) "Поп"
      ["id"]=>
      int(12842970)
      ["image"]=>
      string(47) "https://mp3go.dev/api/tracks/12842970/cover.jpg"
      ["position"]=>
      int(2)
      ["release_id"]=>
      int(2352788)
      ["release_title"]=>
      string(29) "Шарик (Remix Collection)"
      ["title"]=>
      string(41) "Шарик (Lavrushkin & Max Roven Remix)"
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(16) {
      ["artist_id"]=>
      int(215394957)
      ["artist_name"]=>
      string(11) "ATIKA PATUM"
      ["bitrate"]=>
      int(125)
      ["duration"]=>
      string(4) "3:49"
      ["duration_seconds"]=>
      int(229)
      ["file"]=>
      string(214) "https://cdn1.mp3go.dev/api/file/7b1dab3062d50d82493b5721740be3f0.mp3?hash=gAAAAABeFKn-d7hUONcEI4BB75TqwrA7joE1cRujZ2xdqBI7D5L-SpAQ3lKnMJNLn4XKna2XWqChoS1p0Bqw9ltyp-er9hL_0XD615wEno4t8j9G-TUzSRmEvzdZzXhNnJDR8mySVl2S"
      ["file_size"]=>
      string(3) "3.5"
      ["genre_objs"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(115)
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "Поп"
        }
      }
      ["genres"]=>
      string(6) "Поп"
      ["id"]=>
      int(16713124)
      ["image"]=>
      string(47) "https://mp3go.dev/api/tracks/16713124/cover.jpg"
      ["position"]=>
      int(2)
      ["release_id"]=>
      int(2602536)
      ["release_title"]=>
      string(10) "Atikapatum"
      ["title"]=>
      string(25) "Atikapatum (Extended Mix)"
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
    }
    [3]=>
    array(16) {
      ["artist_id"]=>
      int(9080857)
      ["artist_name"]=>
      string(17) "Макс Корж"
      ["bitrate"]=>
      int(125)
      ["duration"]=>
      string(4) "4:15"
      ["duration_seconds"]=>
      int(255)
      ["file"]=>
      string(214) "https://cdn1.mp3go.dev/api/file/48371e87c82cac0d284b2f1073e74ac1.mp3?hash=gAAAAABeFKn-d7hUONcEI4BB75TqwrA7joE1cRujZ2xdqBI7D5L-SpAQ3lKnMJNLn4XKna2XWqChoS1p0Bqw9ltyp-er9hL_0XD615wEno4t8j9G-TUzSRmEvzdZzXhNnJDR8mySVl2S"
      ["file_size"]=>
      string(3) "3.9"
      ["genre_objs"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(110)
          ["name"]=>
          string(6) "Рэп"
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(111)
          ["name"]=>
          string(21) "Русский рэп"
        }
        [2]=>
        array(2) {
          ["id"]=>
          int(113)
          ["name"]=>
          string(13) "Хип-хоп"
        }
      }
      ["genres"]=>
      string(21) "Русский рэп"
      ["id"]=>
      int(19166884)
      ["image"]=>
      string(47) "https://mp3go.dev/api/tracks/19166884/cover.jpg"
      ["position"]=>
      int(1)
      ["release_id"]=>
      int(2755177)
      ["release_title"]=>
      string(21) "2 типа людей"
      ["title"]=>
      string(21) "2 типа людей"
      ["year"]=>
      int(2019)
    }
```

не как не могу от него вывести наприер титле из всех масивов например из ид 1,2 ...

Comment: print_r($arr[0]['genre_objs'][0]['id']);

Comment: а возможно через форич?

Comment: если так показывает, то можно сделать так $set=count($arr[0]['genre_objs']);

Comment: for($i = 0; $i <= $set; $i++) {print_r($arr[0]['genre_objs'][$i]['id']);}

Answer (score 0):

```
foreac($arr["result"] as $resultItem){
    echo $resultItem["title"] . "<br>";
}
```